# How to extract data from oracle database and save in Google cloud platform

Tags: oracle, google-cloud-platform

Need to extract the data from oracle database and stored in Google cloud platform. Data is around 10 TB. Is it possible through Spark? Data has to transfer monthly once. Data to be stored and processed in GCP as follows :

Oracle database to Cloud storage (not has to do CSV Export) then it will be clean and prepared in Dataprep which will be further process through Dataflow and then last it will be get stored under Big Query (from big query data scientist will use data for their model creation).

No third party tool to be used during this. Any open source tool is allowed.

I am thinking to extract data from spark (though use of DataProc for spark job) and store it in GCP (any one Cloud storage or big table or big query). Through cloud sql - it is not possible, since it does not support for oracle database.

Any new architecture is also fine, if my above logic is wrong. Please suggest. 
Thank you.

Comment: Store it where in GCP? How quickly do you need to transfer it? You need to share much more info about your requirements. This is not enough info.

Answer (score 0):

Your architecture sounds good. Just some advices:

- If you query your database from spark job, and you perform transform in the same time, you increase the risk of network outage and the difficulties to resume your processing (see bellow)
- The pattern: Cloud Storage -> Dataflow -> BigQuery is perfect for batch processing, once a month like yours.
- Cloud SQL can't match your need (No Oracle support and database limited to 10TB)
- BigQuery doesn't match oracle feature (like Cloud SQL engine (MySQL and PostGre), not the same dialect for Function, stored procedure, queries,..) but it's petabyte scale database. Designed for analytics (don't expect response time in millisesonds for a website usage for example, query take at least 1s) -> Exception for Datastudio data visualization where you can plug BI Engine, an in memory cache that allow you to speed up your BigQuery query for Datastudio
- BigTable is design for timeseries with a high throughput requirement; Not your case, your are in batch mode.

About the data transfer, from my point of view, it's easier to resume a file transfert than a database transaction.

I mean that if you use spark to query your Oracle database and perform the extract/transform that you want, and if a connexion failure occur, your whole process can fail and restart. Or you have to implement a lot of smart engineering to cope with this type of issue.

On the other side, if you have file, the extract of your Oracle database performed locally, it's easy with `gsutil` to resume these transfer. In addition, you query locally your database and it's more efficient than a query through network. To improve the file transfer performance of your 10TB files, you can have a look to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NlevtGlo-E0) for large files; there are other videos in the series for small files if it's your case.

Comment: In oracle database, almost each tables are around 5 GB, and there are around 500 tables or even more. In each month data will be increasing, so in next month only difference data has to get uploaded. Whether gsutil will work in this scenario? But after having success in batch mode, next step will be to make it real time. The pain point is how to load data in GCP any storage, then cleansing and removing unwanted data.

Comment: Longer you have to keep the connexion up between your Oracle data base and GCP, higher is the risk of network outage. You have to deal with this risk and choose the solution that feat your requirements and your dev and supervision capabilities.

Comment: I will extract the data from oracle database through Spark, and then I want to store this data from spark to any storage in Google cloud platform. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, use Cloud Storage. However, I'm not Hadoop/spark expert (I never use it in production) and I don't know what operator to use for this...

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully my reply is not too late, but I will post it anyways...

You might be able to cut down on some of the steps you mentioned, but it all depends on the details of your data transform. There's too many possibilities to list, but I think you are looking for a set of options to choose from. If you are stil investigating options, please see below.

- I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-oracle-to-cloud-spanner) article which shows how to migrate from Oracle OLTP to Spanner or from OLAP to BigQuery. There is an entire workflow, which is too long to list here.
- Also, [this](https://cloud.google.com/products/data-transfer/) article shows general transfer options such as "Online Transfer", "Transfer Service", "Transfer Appliance" and "Bigquery Data Transfer Service" at the top of the page. The rest of the page provides information on how to choose the right service based on the amount of data and throughput.

I hope that the above points you in the right direction if it's not too late.

Answer (score 0):

The following link shows that you can use Cloud Dataflow to read directly from Oracle database to BigQuery. If you want to perform any ETL, you might need to add couple more steps in between.

https://github.com/rrakesh2690/dataengineering